# Provisioning iBKS 105 to Eddystone UID

Tags: beacon, eddystone

I have an iBKS 105 and I turned it on to serve Eddystone UID.  However, the Google Beacon tool cant seem to discover the beacon.  How to provision the beacon to serve Eddstone UID?  Any help would be nice!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you swiping down on the beacon screen to force a scan?  Can you see the beacon using another tool like Locate? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate

Comment: Update: i managed to provision it to serve eddystone uid. Google beacon tools is able to detect it and register it.  I am able to make my changes using Google beacons dashboard.  However, i dont see any notifications not nearby messages similar to the keynote presentation.  I am using a nexus 5

Comment: new question:  can Eddystone UID be detected by iOS devices?